# Login parameters of unknown origin?

Tags: python, authentication, parameters

I want to login to a website with Python but could not find where the parameters in the login url came from.
I've checked all the urls before the login, but none of them (headers, cookies, etc.) show these parameters.

The login url looks like this: `https://www.example.com/auth/login?key=iH3_8aYEZZy7iQJliEospQ&expires=1598750085`

the `key` and `expires` parameters here come automatically as variable with this url.

Is there something I don't know about this or these parameters come with a hidden API?

Comment: It looks like session data created from the previous page. Are you going directly to the login page or being redirected?

Comment: The login url comes directly like this and there is no data in any link that came before that.

Comment: Then it's probably a user key\token. You may need to sign up to get that.

Comment: I don't know, maybe there is something I missed there, would you review it if I sent the login information for this site?

Comment: Yes - I can check it

Comment: Thanks, how can I contact you.


Edit: I saw your e-mail address on your CV, I can send it there if you are still actively using it

Comment: yes - send it there

Comment: okay, I sent it.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the site you sent.

The `key` and `expires` parameters are generated on the front end in javascript. You can use the Chrome dev tools to search the web page script files for a specific term. In this case, I searched for 'login'. It looks like those parameters are generated by a couple functions buried in the script.

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

I see 3 options you can try from here:

- Dig through the script and find the logic that creates the parameters
- Download the scripts and use javascript to generate the parameters
- Use an automation tool like selenium to log in through the browser

Comment: Hello Mike67, the reason I haven't done this is my problem is not resolved yet, I can't adapt these codes to python because I don't have java knowledge :/